# How to remove postback on linkbutton inside gridview?

Tags: asp.net, button, gridview, postback, asynchronous-postback

I'd like to ask on how to prevent post back when a `LinkButton` inside the `GridView` is clicked?

My current implementation is that, I have a `GridView` with customer details and the button link which is the ID link button, once this link button is clicked the customer details will be shown on their respective fields (i.e. textbox, etc), but I want it to look like more interactive and faster when clicking the said button by removing Post back. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Is the page refreshing when `linkbutton` is clicked? If yes, then it seems you want that page should not refresh. Best option is to go for AJAX. If data to be shown isn't heavy, you can query it & keep it hidden & subsequently play with it when `linkbutton` is clicked.

Comment: Check out this example: http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/tutorials/IntroductionUpdatePanel.aspx

Comment: Why use a LinkButton in the first place? LinkButtons are designed to postback - that is their _raison d'être_! Just use an HTML anchor e.g. <a href="#" onclick="loadViaAjax();">click me</a>

Comment: @tomtroughton can you give me an example pls? thanks.

this is my current code

<asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkView" CssClass="View" Text ='<%# Eval("ID")%>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: @tomtroughton I got it, I used anchor by already. Thanks to you my friend. I will if it will work in my jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to confirm my answer after our comments, replace this...

```
<asp:TemplateField> <ItemTemplate> <asp:LinkButton ID="linkView" CssClass="View" Text ='<%# Eval("ID")%>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>
```

...with this...

```
<asp:TemplateField> <ItemTemplate> <a href="#" onclick="return loadViaAjax();"><%# Eval("ID")%></a> </ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>
```

...where `loadViaAjax` is a Javascript function which populates your customer fields via AJAX or some other means. Ensure this function returns `false` to prevent the browser responding to the anchor click.

Please mark this as the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Another option is to add `OnClientClick="return false;"` (or if you already have something in there, add the return false to the end)